# Length mismatch: Expected axis has ' ' elements, new values have 1 elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mismatch

i'm trying to select a specific column from the data set but i always get the same error :
Length mismatch: Expected axis has 31 elements, new values have 1 elements

[image]

Comment: this is the script :

import yfinance as yf
import yesg
ticker_info = yesg.get_esg_full(report_ticker)
esg_data = pd.DataFrame(ticker_info)
esg_data.columns = [str(ticker_info.Ticker)]

esg_data.loc[['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score',
              'ESG Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy'],:]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Based on comments exchanged with OP, here is code that will work:

```py
esg_data[['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score', 'ESG Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

The code in your question is:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import yesg
ticker_info = yesg.get_esg_full(report_ticker)
esg_data = pd.DataFrame(ticker_info)
esg_data.columns = [str(ticker_info.Ticker)]

esg_data.loc[['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score',
    'ESG-Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy'],:]
```

The line giving an error is: `esg_data.columns = [str(ticker_info.Ticker)]`

The error is: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 31 elements, new values have 1 elements`

This reasons for this error message are:

- esg_data.columns is the column index for a dataframe with 31 columns (namely `esg_data`), therefore to update it one must provide a list-like object of the same length
- the object actually provided is `[str(ticker_info.Ticker)]`, which is a list with 1 element (namely `ticker_info.Ticker` converted to a str)

You have stated that:

> i'm trying to select a specific column from the data set

If you're trying to select the `Ticker` column from `esg_data`, you can do this:

```py
columnToSelect = esg_data.Ticker
```

If you're trying to select the multiple columns from `esg_data` in the line of your code that reads `esg_data.loc[['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score', 'ESG-Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy'],:]`, this may be problematic since the first argument to `loc` should be a list of index labels (not column labels) and the second argument (in this case, `:`) will be interpreted as a list of column labels.

If (as I suspect) you were hoping to select the *row* (or rows) of `esg_data` with `Ticker` column value corresponding to  `str(ticker_info.Ticker)` and then select from this object the column values `['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score', 'ESG-Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']`, you should be able to do this as follows:

```py
rowsMatchingTicker = esg_data[esg_data.Ticker == str(ticker_info.Ticker)]
desiredColumnsMatchingTicker = rowsMatchingTicker[:, ['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score',
    'ESG-Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']]
```

... or (more succintly):

```py
desiredColumnsMatchingTicker = esg_data.loc[esg_data.Ticker == str(ticker_info.Ticker), 
    ['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score',
    'ESG-Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response ! 

i tried it but unfortunately it dosen't work .

Comment: i tired this and it works :D : 

esg_data.loc[:,['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score',
    'ESG Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']]

Comment: OK, apparently you just want all of the rows in `esg_data` for the indicated columns, with no further filtering required to narrow it down to the ticker of interest. You can probably also just do this: `esg_data[['Total-Score','E-Score','S-Score','G-Score', 'ESG Performance','total Percentile','peer Group','max Highest Controversy']]`, though the code in your comment is fine as well.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Please consider marking my update answer 'accepted'.